# How to access deployed war in wildfly 10?

Tags: java, maven, wildfly

I have written simple rest service now i wan't to test it i have run WildFly and it has already deployed my war file but I can't see this
war file in my browser on this link below browser shows me 404 error
 what should i do?

### **http://localhost:9990/standalone/deployments/User-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war**

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask first...

Comment: There isn't much information to go on here. Perhaps you should [edit] your question and include the wildfly log file, configuration and any information that could help track down the problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Port 9990 is used to access Wildfly's management console. Your deployments are served on port 8080 (assuming that you are running a standard out-of-the-box configuration).

The war file is not accessed by its deployment path but by its *root context*. This may be different from the war file name.

To find the context root of your deployment, look in the Wildfly log file for a line containing the text "Registered web context: ". This line tells you the path on the server under which your deployment can be accessed. Now simply prefix this path with `http://localhost:8080/` and you should see your deployment.

For instance, my server log contains the line

```
20:51:55,427 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-8) JBAS017534: Registered web context: /ejbtest-web
```

This tells me that /ejbtest-web is the context root of my war file. To access it I have to use `http://localhost:8080/ejbtest-web`.